# How to solve BigQuery "request could not be completed" error?

Tags: google-bigquery

In Google BigQuery, when I enter the following query I get the following error. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks,

Josh

```
CREATE MODEL `finance-ml-jdb:FOREX.EURGBP_Model`
      OPTIONS( model_type         = 'linear_reg',
               input_label_cols   = ['bidclose'],
               ls_init_learn_rate = .15,
               l1_reg             = 1,
               max_iterations     = 5
              ) AS
SELECT
    bidopen,
    bidhigh,
    bidlow,
    askopen,
    askclose,
    asklow,
    tickqty
FROM `finance-ml-jdb.FOREX.EURGBP`
```

> An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

Comment: File a bug on the [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:187149%2B) with a job ID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your SELECT statement - it is missing `bidclose` field in the output while it is defined as a label for a model

Just add it into SELECT list and you should be good (unless something else will come up - like - as an example - having NULL values for `bidclose` in some rows - so you can add `WHERE NOT bidclose IS NULL`)

Also fix below line to use `.` instead of `:`

```
CREATE MODEL `finance-ml-jdb.FOREX.EURGBP_Model`
```

If this still does not help - try to run with default values like below

```
CREATE MODEL `finance-ml-jdb.FOREX.EURGBP_Model`
      OPTIONS( model_type         = 'linear_reg',
               input_label_cols   = ['bidclose']
              ) AS
SELECT
    bidopen,
    bidclose,
    bidhigh,
    bidlow,
    askopen,
    askclose,
    asklow,
    tickqty
FROM `finance-ml-jdb.FOREX.EURGBP`
```

Comment: Your comment makes sense but after I correct this Instill get the same error unfortunately.